# Is there a way to add a bearing/heading visual to Here Maps marker?

Tags: here-api

I was fiddling a bit with [Here Maps](http://www.here.com/) and with some some of the examples [Here Javascript API Explorer](http://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/api-explorer) and [Here Maps on GitHub](http://heremaps.github.io/examples/).

I tried to see if there's already a way to just add a visual bearing attribute in addition to longitude and latitude and have something like a small tip appear to the marker. This feels like something that many would like to have, so just to check I haven't missed anything obvious...

- Is there a way to add visual bearing information to markers?

  - If not, does anyone know if there's an example of using a custom marker to achieve this I just couldn't locate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no bearing/heading control ready available within the API - you will have to create a custom [map component](http://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/maps/topics/map-components-and-ui.html) of your own. The usual way of doing this would be to inject some HTML as a new DOM element within the map control.

Firstly define your custom `HtmlControl` as shown:

```
function extend(B, A) {
    function I() {}
    I.prototype = A.prototype;
    B.prototype = new I();
    B.prototype.constructor = B;
}

function HtmlControl (html, id) {
    nokia.maps.map.component.Component.call(this);
    this.init(html, id);
}

extend(HtmlControl,
        nokia.maps.map.component.Component);


HtmlControl.prototype.init = function (html, id) {
    that = this;
    that.id = id
    that.set("node",  document.createElement("div"));   
    that.node.innerHTML = html;
};

HtmlControl.prototype.getId = function() { 
    return "HtmlControl." + this.id;
};

HtmlControl.prototype.attach = function(map) {
    map.getUIContainer().appendChild(this.node);
};

HtmlControl.prototype.detach = function(display) {
    map.getUIContainer().removeChild(this.node);
};
```

Then set up the `map` and add the custom component as shown:

```
 htmlControl = new HtmlControl(
   "<img id='compass' style='left:4em;top:1em;width:100px;height:100px' src='...'/>", "Compass");
map.components.add(htmlControl);
```

The source file for the `<img>` element will need to hold the compass image. This is most likely to be an image with due North pointing upwards since the map control is based on the [Normalized Mercator projection](http://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/enterprise-map-tile/topics/key-concepts.html)

Alternatively look at using the [Map Image API](http://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/enterprise-map-image/topics/resource-map.html) and investigate the `ra` parameter to rotate the map.

Comment: Thanks! I think I got the gist of the matter now. If I bump into issues, well, I can ask a more specific question. Cheers!